# Ожидания ответа ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. В начале выполнение js скрипта мне необходимо отправить ajax запрос, получить данные с него и только потом продолжить выполнение скрипта. Сейчас у меня такой код
       var user_data = getdata(count);
Метод getdata отправляет get-запрос к скрипту. Проблема в том, что когда переменная user_data нужна, она еще пуста, т.к. мы не получили ответ от сервера. Как действовать в этом случае? метод getdata возвращает массив от JSON.parse

Comment: Если переменная user_data нужна до того как получен ответ, то ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: Можно использовать функции обратного вызова. Я могу ошибаться, если не понял вопроса. `false` решит проблему `xhr.open('POST', url, false);`. Скрипт не пойдёт дальше, пока запрос не выполнится

Comment: Переделать скрипт таким образом, чтобы он выполнялся в callback по завершении ajax запроса. Синхронные запросы уже давно всюду отменяются или уже не работают. Указать async = false можно только в Worker-е (отдельном потоке), что будет практически равнозначно запуску обычного асинхронного запроса в главном потоке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему заключением всего необходимого когда в `$.get("имя скрипта" , { user_number: count} ).done(function( data ) {`

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать джекверевский `$.when` и его promise https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Если в `$.when()` передать только один deferred-объект, то он просто возвратит его promise-версию. Помимо deferred-объектов в `$.when()` можно указывать любые другие js-объекты. `jQuery` всегда будет определять их состояние как успешно выполненное.

Пример:

```
$.when( $.ajax("test.aspx") ).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    alert( jqXHR.status ); // выводит 200
});
```

Соответственно пихаете в *when* свой запрос, а после его исполнения доделываете свои грязные делишки:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ) ).done(function( data ) {
    // делаете что-то что вам нужно сделать
    // var response = data[ 0 ] + data[ 1 ]; 
    // alert(response);
    // ...
    // ...
});
```

Comment: `ajax` уже возвращает promise, нет нужды `when` использовать

Comment: @Grundy да, наверное `when` имеет смысл когда надо несколько одновременно асинхронно запустить